# Auto joining newly created VM/Servers as kubernetes node to master

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-pod

Hi I am working on Google Cloud platform where I am not using GKE. Rather I am creating k8s cluster manually. Following is my setup,
Total 11 server

1. Out of these 5 servers would be static servers and don't need any scaling
2. remaining 5 server would need up scaling if CPU or RAM consumption goes beyond certain
   limit. i.e. I will spin only 3 servers initially and if CPU/RAM threshold is crossed then I will spin 2 more using Google Cloud Load balancer.
3. 1 k8s Master server

To implement this load balancer I have already created one Custom Image on which I have installed docker and kubernetes. Using this I have create one instance template and then instance group.

Now the problem statement is ,
Although I have created image with everything installed , When I am creating a instance group in which 3 VM are being created , these VMs does not automatically connect to my k8s master. Is there any way to automatically connect newly created VM as a node to k8s master so that I do not have run join command manually on each server ?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Since your stack is custom your requirement may be custom as well. You can try GCP's Google Cloud Composer which is cloud orchestration tool. Or you can use [Terraform with GCP](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so that I do not have run join command manually on each server

I am assuming that you can successfully run the join command to join the newly created VMs to the Kubernetes master manually. 
If that is the case, you can use the `startup-script` feature in the Google Compute Engine. 
Here is the documentation: 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux#passing-directly 
 
In short, `startup-script` is the feature from Google Compute Engine to automatically run our customized script during start-up.

And, the script could look something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
kubeadm join .......
```

Comment: This worked perfectly as I expected. Thanks for the help.